# Where do I enter moment.js code so a DataTables column appears in my chosen format?

Tags: datatables, momentjs

I want to make data like 2022/12/15 (imported from Google Sheets at the moment of page load) display as "Dec 15" in one column, and as "Thu" in another column.

I found the format codes:
`moment().format("MMM d"); // "Dec 15"` and
`moment().format("ddd"); // "Thu"`.

I read https://momentjs.com/docs/ and https://momentjs.com/guides/, but could not find:
Where do I enter that code?

Can I skip entering that code, and instead just enter this?:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 4,
                render: DataTable.render.datetime('MMM d'),
            },
        ],
    });
});
```

Perhaps I should separate my questions into different posted questions, but I imagine it will be more helpful for future readers to find the combined challenges asked and answered in a single thread.

I'm using the WordPress plugin "Inline Google Spreadsheet Viewer", which is built on DataTables.
[Edit: I realized I should not paste that code into inline_gdocs_viewer.php, and intended to paste it into igsv-datatables.js.  I could not however figure out where to paste within that file. What should I look for to know where to insert it?   (The author of that plugin publicly announced that no more support will be given.) Should I post the contents of the js file somewhere so you can see it?]
[Edit 2: Would entering that code make column 5 always displayed in MMM d format, even if I want column 5 to be displayed in a different format?  Shouldn't specifying what format to apply to which column happen when I create a page / post and use the shortcode to embed the spreadsheet?]
(I read the plugin's documentation and I read DataTables documentation.)

If my table doesn't have a name, what do I use instead of #example?  Do I need to name my table?  If so, how?  (I tried to find the answer at, for example, https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp.)

The source for the longer code came from a live example where the dates were in column 5, but the code says "targets:4".  To apply the code to column 3 (for example), should I enter targets:2? I read https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render, but bizarrely that didn't address this basic question.

If you're wondering if I upgraded DataTables from the old version that comes with Inline Google Spreadsheet Viewer, yes I did.
If you're wondering if I got the script array to call moment.js, I might have.  Into the scripts array I added

```
,
'moment' => array(
'src' => plugins_url('moment.min.js', __FIL__),
'deps' => array( 'moment' )
)
```

I'm not sure about the "deps" part. Does it mean dependencies? Was I right to use "moment" twice in that code?

If you only know a possible answer to one of these questions, that's better than nothing, so please do share what you can.

I know the Moment team recommends you choose a different library than Moment for new projects, but DataTables to this day recommends Moment for sorting by Day of the week or sorting by Date.

Thanks

Using moment.js 2.29.2 and DataTables 1.13.1.

---

What I tried, and what I expected:
I read the documentation for all the programs, and I read forum discussions for all the programs, and I studied examples, expecting to find where to enter the code, but nowhere could I find what to do with it.  It was always assumed that that part was already known.

Comment: I found the longer section of code should pasted not in the php file but in the file igsv-datatables.js, and edited my post to reflect that.  Can't figure out where to paste the code within that file.

Comment: Would entering that code (including "targets:4" make column 5 always displayed in MMM d format, even if I want column 5 to be displayed in a different format?  Shouldn't specifying what format to apply to which column happen when I create a page / post and use the shortcode to embed the spreadsheet?

Comment: "Javascript indexes the first element in the array as 0. So column 1 is referenced with targets: 0, etc."  That's why column 5 was affected when the code said "targets:4".